# Run Python script in Azure Webjobs

Tags: python, azure, python-3.6, azure-webjobs

"I'm trying to run my script in Azure webjobs, but it keeps giving me the following error:
[image]

"My .zip looks like this:
[image]

"I already reinstalled numpy and also tried to upgrade the package. I'm taking the packages from the path C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages."

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Please also read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough. Copy and paste your errors, formatted as code, starting from the line that reads `Traceback (most recent call last):`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the way I created my .zip folder. It worked fine when I followed the steps on this question's answer [Run Python script in Azure Webjobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69533179/run-python-script-in-azure-webjobs?noredirect=1#comment123043611_69533179)

And then added
import sys sys.path.append('D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\jobs\continuous\python2\myenv\Lib\site-packages') in the beginning of my code.